# Scala - How to create a class with a constructor that receives an object as parameter

Tags: scala, constructor

Igot  two classes in Scala - one is a property of the other. I want to create a smart constructor for the parent class, but I don't really know what are the best practices to do it. I've done some research, but didn't find a satisfactory solution/explanation.

Here are my classes.

```
final class Role(role: String) //child

object Role:
  def isRoleValid(role: String): Boolean =
    val pattern = "([a-zA-Z])+".r
    pattern.matches(role)
      
  def newRole(role: String): Role = Role(role)
    
  def from(role: String): Option[Role] =
    if(isRoleValid(role)) Some(newRole(role))
    else None
```

```
final class NurseRequirement(role: Role, number: Int) //Parent

object NurseRequirement:
  def isNumberValid(number: Int): Boolean = number > 0
  //What should I do to validate the Role object??
```

Comment: Did you intend to nest `object Role` inside of `Role`, or is it just indentation mistake? (By the way: triple quotes are way easier to get right)

Comment: Yes, I did. The object belongs to the class.

Comment: Since there is no colon after `Role(...)`, I'd still assume that you meant "companion object", not "nested object". As it is now, the compiler would whine at you that the second "line is indented too far to the right".

Comment: Forgot to add it... Already fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you actually wanted companion object with something like this:

```
  def from(s: String, n: Int): Option[NurseRequirement] =
    if isNumberValid(n) 
    then Role.from(s).map(NurseRequirement(_, n))
    else None
```

If you get into situation where you have more of such optional subcomponents, you can get rid of the nested `if`s by using the `for`-comprehensions on `Option`, i.e. something like:

```
  def from(s: String, n: Int) =
    for
      r <- Role.from(s)
      m <- Option(n).filter(isNumberValid)
    yield NurseRequirement(r, m)
```

Comment: You are totally right! I just did a little research on companion object and that's exactly what I wanted! Your answer is perfect for my needs. I'm sorry if I was a little bit confusing. Still in very beginning of the process of learning Scala.

Comment: `isRoleValid` missed here

Comment: @MikhailIonkin `isRoleValid` is an implementation detail of `Role.from`, I'd assume that it's better not to reference it directly in `NurseRequirement`.